# Unable to SSH in EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am unable to ssh AWS ec2 instance. It shows error Permission denied (public Key).I have tried to generate new pem key

```
# ssh-keygen -y -f /path/to/keypair.pem
```

and added it in Instance Settings View/Change User Data

```
#cloud-config 
#ssh_deletekeys: false
#ssh_authorized_keys:
# - ssh-rsa ENTER YOUR PUBLIC KEY HERE ... 
#cloud_final_modules: - [ssh, always]
```

But it didn't work and I also tried this tutorial
    https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/recover-access-lost-key-pair/

Still it is not working.

Comment: can you be specific with the link you have followed ? In case you have lost your private key you need to detach the root volume attached to a new instance update the authorised with new public key detach it and attach it again

Comment: Could you please edit your question and describe what you are actually wanting to achieve? Are you wanting to launch and login to a new Amazon EC2 instance, or are you attempting to ssh to an existing instance? If it is an existing instance, have you previously been able to ssh to it? What AMI was used to launch the instance (eg Amazon Linux 2)? Also, please show us the command you are using to SSH into the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do wont work. Neither will the answer @Rajeev provided. If it was a file permission error you would see a message indicating the .pem file had unsecure read permissions. What I suspect you'll need to do is kill off that instance and relaunch with a new key. Will be easier than troubleshooting it, and you can make a snapshot to launch a new instance from if you have done a lot of config on it already.

AWS best practices state instances should be treated as ephemeral. Follow those guidelines and you'll save yourself a lot of hassle in the long run.